# Angular 5 replace whole page

Tags: routes, angular5

I have some pages with no common element (no navbar).

As far as I understand, Angular routing can change part of the page by adding <router-outlet> where you want a component to be inserted.

But what if I want to change the whole page ?

Thank you for your help